# Reading new exchange messages

Tags: .net, vb.net, exchangewebservices

I've been reading a lot on using Exchange Web Services to read emails in a supplied mailbox in a .NET program.  This is very close to something that I am attempting to do, and would like the advice of people who have managed to use this service.

Essentially, I want a single service to run which monitors the inbound messages for all mailboxes and scans for a specific piece of text and act on it.  What it will do is unimportant, but ideally it needs to watch all or several designated mailboxes at the same time without polling each one in turn.

Is this even possible or does it only work one mailbox at a time?

Comment: what you are looking for is called `IDLE` , choose a library that supports both exchange server and IDLE ....

Answer (score 0):

With EWS (or any of the client API) you have a one to one relationship with Mailboxes so for every Inbox you want to watch there would essentially be a Subscription if you where using EWS Notifications https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx or some process to poll the Mailbox in question.

Other alternatives is if you are using Oprem Exchange is write a Transport agent https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125012(v=exchg.150).aspx and do the processing while the Message is in the Transport Pipeline before it is delivered to any mailboxes. You can also just journal all the Messages with a Mail Flow Rule https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj898487(v=exchg.150).aspx that are sent and received by a server to one mailbox and then just process the messages from that central mailbox.